# Creating and managing a byte buffer in memory, in C and/or C++, that can automatically resize as needed

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, data-structures, file-io

When programming in C and/or C++, how does one set up byte-buffer in-memory structure, such that it can automatically resize as the situation warrants?

Often, I will want to write some unknown quantity bytes to a buffer, without knowing how much space is needed. I feel like this is a fundamental I/O programming concern – and I don’t know how to approach the problem, let alone solve it.

Specifically, I’m doing this I/O to process image data – the sizes can vary from a few kilobytes on up to hundreds of megabytes, depending on compression settings and (many!) other factors.

My current workaround, in many cases, is to:

1. `open()` a write-mode descriptor on a temporary file, and `write()` my indeterminate quantity of bytes to this file;
2. then call `fsync()` and subsequently `close()` the descriptor;
3. use `stat()` to get the size of the file;
4. re-`open()` the temporary file in read mode;
5. and *then* finally `read()` the entire file back into a newly allocated, properly-sized buffer.

My question, therefore, is a two-parter: one, how problematic is my workaround? and two: how can I accomplish this task using only in-memory structures?

Comment: C++ has `std::vector`, C has `realloc`.

Comment: "automatically" Please define what it means. What kind of interface would qualify?

Comment: @Mat Right, rgr that – but how does one best track and algorithmically resize them in practice?

Comment: "*how problematic is my workaround?* it isn't at all, at least if performance is not an issue.

Comment: @n.m. I was thinking of how e.g. `funopen()` allows for the use of the `FILE*` opaque handle as the front-end interface for an arbitrary structure – in such a context, what are some algorithmic methods for handling initial allocation sizes _qua_ subsequent reallocations

Comment: @n.m. … also, what is a good strategy for expanding the buffer in-place, in terms of doing the least amount of copying?

Comment: A simple linked list can provide the functionality you're looking for. Its memory layout is usually not what we'd expect from a buffer, but so are files; they're just wrapped in an API that makes it look like a file is a single sequence of bytes. So basically you wanna separate the API, which should appear to manage a single buffer, from the implementation, which may manage multiple memory blocks. And using a file to store non-persistent data can be terribly slow.

Comment: Did you consider memory mapping?  That way you don't need to allocate any memory, the file becomes part of the paging system.  See `mmap`:  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html

Comment: Ah OK so a stream-like interface. C++ has std::stringstream. Standard C has no such thing (funopen would qualify but it's not standard). You can wrap a realloc'able buffer in a similar fashion that doesn't involve an actual FILE pointer.

Comment: How much data are you talking about? Do you need save the data on disk?

Comment: What about C's `malloc()` and `realloc()`?

Comment: Double the capacity each time you reallocate.

Comment: Curious: how can one program in C **and** C++? I do get the "or"; you can add "or Java or Python or ..."

Comment: An efficient strategy for a *contiguous* buffer is to increase the buffer size by a factor bigger than 1 when the buffer becomes full. The factor balances overallocation vs. effort copying the data: a small factor is expected to be more memory efficient but causes more copying. If you expect that the original size is about right you may want to choose a smaller factor (e.g., 1.5) while more uncertaintainty probably leads to a bigger value (e.g., 2). In either case, you’d encapsulate the operation into an `insert()` operation (with C++ `std::vector` does just that).

Comment: @usr2564301 programming in “C and C++” is arguably possible due to the fact that C++ behaves much like a superset of C (although strictly speaking it isn’t) – so, say, using the POSIX I/O C functions in a C++ program (like e.g. as I describe in my question) is something I could call “C and C++ programming,” if you will.

Comment: @DietmarKühl thanks, these are exactly the kinds of implementation notes I am looking for. You don’t suppose you have an example of this handy (one you’d find exemplary)?

Comment: @fish2000: as already noted, `std::vector` is an example. `std::string` is another example. Just look at one of the open source implementations, e.g., [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/vector.tcc#L713).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your approach as long as you can make sure the file doesn't change size between steps 3 and 5. It is, actually, the solution that has most probably the best performance.

In case you realize (by counting bytes read vs. buffer size) while `read`ing the file that there is more to read but you run out of buffer space, you can always use `realloc` to increase the buffer by an arbitrary amount. How much that "arbitrary amount" would be depends on the nature of your application and your expected memory situation. If memory is plenty, you might want to over-allocate by factor 1.5 and `realloc` to the actual size once you have read the complete file.

Dynamically re-allocating the buffer has, however, a bit of a speed penalty and might not always be possible when you are working with huge buffers and are already tight on memory (most implementations of `realloc` will temporarily need to hold both the too-small and the re-sized buffer in memory).

Depending on the buffer sizes, your program might also suffer from a performance penalty when resizing the buffer - after all, the contents you already read needs to be copied over to the new, re-sized, buffer.

In C++, you would probably use a `vector` to do the same thing and may run into the very same problems.

One last method to load large files is memory mapping - But this also has the requirement that you need to know how much space you need.

Comment: In C++, if strict contiguity is not a requirement, a `deque` might be a good choice.

Comment: @BenVoigt Strict contiguity is something I'd assume when the OP is talking about image data. Otherwise, you're right.

Comment: Are you sure that "the solution that has most probably the best performance"? If the file was fully cached, it'd match an in-memory dynamic data structure, but that's not guaranteed. Worse, he's calling `fsync`, which is a blocking I/O operation. A file might be a convenient abstraction to work with, but in this case that's all it gives. Any memory-based alternative will most likely be much faster.

Comment: @eran The comparison was  "growing buffers" vs. "allocate all and load", i.e. the OP's algorithm vs. anything that uses dynamic buffers. `mmap` will indeed be a somewhat faster for the latter. On large blocks fully allocated and loaded in one go, `mmap` isn't significantly faster than traditional file-based operations. It plays its cards when random access to random portions in large files that don't fit in memory as a whole is required.